# SQL connection to localhost

Tags: c#, phpmyadmin, localhost, sqlconnection, sqlexception

I install DENWER and with help of built-in PhpMyAdmin create a database on localhost. When i connect to database in my C# application i get "SQL Exception was unhandled". Dont understand where is my mistake...

Code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; User Id=root; Password=; Initial Catalog=MyDB");
connection.Open();
```

Comment: And what does the SQL Exception message say?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a MySQL DB then?

Comment: 1. Its on russian, i dont think it will be helpful

Comment: @Ethan Francis's point is that SqlConnection is the SQL Server client. You'll need to use something else for MySQL.

Comment: I'm kinda new to coding but the above answer from Rup worked for me, remember to add the using statment using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool, I assume you've actually installed MySQL. Obviously you should check that you have a database installed and running before you go any further. Can you connect to it in phpMyAdmin or with the mysql command line tools?

Try installing the [MySQL .NET connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), add a reference to the MySql.Data assembly and then:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(
               "server=localhost;user id=root;password=secret;database=MyDB;");
connection.Open();
```

In general you should wrap your connection, command and data reader objects in `using` if you can so that they'll get disposed properly

```
using(var connection = new MySqlConnection("..."))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "...";

    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

etc. or wrap in a try-finally and clean up the objects in the finally.